# SQL Update not updating records in access

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-update, database-connection, oledb

Trying to update the values of **Comment** and **ProgressValue** inside a table in access. The message box at the end **pops up** but none of the values are changed.

```
 Sub UpdateWeeklyReport()
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim com As OleDbCommand
    con = New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\ProjectDatabase.mdb")


    com = New OleDbCommand("Update WeeklyReport Set Comment = @Comment, ProgressValue = @ProgressValue Where [EntryDate]='" & CBDate.SelectedValue.ToString & "' AND [AdminNo]=" & CBAdmin.SelectedValue & " AND [ClassCode]='" & CBClass.SelectedItem.ToString & "'", con)
    con.Open()
    com.Parameters.Add("@Comment", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = txtComment.Text
    com.Parameters.Add("@ProgressValue", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CBProgress.Text

    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Report Changed")
    intialconnection()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Check your where condition ... put a break point, look at your SQLCommand, my money is on 'where' condition being wrong and not finding any data to update

Comment: all those where condition values can and should also be parameters, especially the date!

Comment: Put a break point and see what your com variable returns, there should be a bad sqlcommand returned.